# Check failed: gl_version_string. The GL proc resolver's glGetString(GL_VERSION) with flutter

Tags: flutter

I ran **flutter run -d linux** and here is the error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode... Building Linux application... [FATAL:flutter/shell/gpu/gpu_surface_gl_delegate.cc(50)] Check failed: gl_version_string. The GL proc resolver's glGetString(GL_VERSION) failed Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly. Error launching application on Linux.
```

Comment: Which graphics card is present on your system >?

Comment: Graphics card is present on my system is nvidia geforce

Answer (score 1):

You have To change your Nvidia proprietary drivers To open source drivers if You don’t understant the answer is explained here with on this repository : https://github.com/fermat28/flutter_shell_gpu_surface_gl_delegate.cc_error_fix

Comment: That solved it for me. I have an outdated prorietary nvidia driver.